# Select Statement doing a "for each" thing, then returning itself

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data pipeline. I would like to do some conditional transformations on the data in a fast way. It seems like I could just build up an enumeration without triggering it till the end like so:

```
var data = read();
if (!adminUser) data = data.Select(d => {d.ClearAdminOnlyFields(); return d;});
if (summarize) data = data.Select(d => {d.ClearVerboseFields(); return d;});
if (translate) data = data.Select(d => {d.Translate(culture); return d;});
return data;
```

The data above is thousands of items. I have tried googling this style of using select, but can't find any good examples of it being used. It seems like folks always enumerate with a `.ToList()` then do the transforms in a `.ForEach()`, but multiple enumerations like that should be slower! It seems like it would also be slower to do one big `foreach` with the if check inside it.

My question is: Am I wrong about this being faster? If so, can you explain what alternative is faster/better and why.

Comment: Looks like calling the list `ForEach` is not quite 2x slower, but close: dotnetfiddle.net/67JjRL The manual foreach was faster than the selects, though. Probly due to the huge linq overhead or something. Makes sense, as multiple enumerations require multiple setups. With linq you can load stuff into memory once and then do lots with it, but in this case the overhead of linq doesn't outweigh the time saved with memory, probably..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* do this, not because it doesn't work, but because it violates the common expectation of what `Select` does (transforms data without side effects).

You should use a `foreach` for this kind of logic instead. You should be able to do this with a single `foreach`, enumerating only once. Using `Select` to do this is not faster.

Comment: I was still skeptical, so I tried a fiddle. Looks like the list-foreach is the worst, but the manual foreach even with `if`s inside is indeed faster: https://dotnetfiddle.net/67JjRL  (unless this test has errors, which is very possible.)

Comment: Yes - using LINQ to only evaluate each `if` a single time is nifty, but mature compilers are *very good* at optimizing repeated evaluations of an unchanging conditional inside a loop.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a classic case of me thinking I can beat compiler optimizations, when I can't. Feel free to link the fiddle in your answer, if you think it's up to snuff enough for posterity.